# Sonarqube build wrapper for distutils

Tags: python, c++, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a python project with a significant amount of C/C++ code, and I use distutils to build the project. When using sonarqube, I received the following message:

> By using the `build-wrapper-output.bypass=true` property, you'll switch to an "at best" mode that could result in false-positives and false-negatives.

(Note: message modified from the original for clarity)

Is it possible to use the sonarqube build wrapper when compiling with distutils?

Comment: Hi, SonarC++ is a commercial product, so please address your problem to commercial support

Comment: I am using sonarqube.com, which is free for open source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, SonarC++ build-wrapper is generic and you can use it with distutils. Follow the documentation on sonarqube.com which provides examples on how to setup the analysis of C/C++ projects.